# UndefVarError With Julia TidierData Package

Tags: julia

I am trying to use the `TidierData` package in Julia.
I have imported the correct packages, but when I try to run one of the macros (such as `@glimpse`), I get the error `"LoadError: UndefVarError: @glimpse not defined"`.
Am I missing something?

Here's a MWE:

```
using DataFrames
using TidierData
df = DataFrame(a=1:4, b=["M", "F", "F", "M"])
@glimpse(df)
```

I have tried to wrap the `@glimpse` call in a chain thinking this would solve the issue, but I have not had success.

For example,

```
@chain df begin
    @glimpse()
end
```

gives the exact same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I had a previous version of `TidierData` installed on my computer which did not have `@glimpse()`.
By checking `Pkg.status()` I found out that the version installed is `v0.10.0`.
By typing `] up TidierData@v0.12.0` in the REPL, my package version was updated.
Now, running my MWE gives the following output:

```
4×2 DataFrame
 Row │ a      b      
     │ Int64  String
─────┼───────────────
   1 │     1  M
   2 │     2  F
   3 │     3  F
   4 │     4  M

Rows: 4
Columns: 2
.a             Int64          1, 2, 3, 4
.b             String         M, F, F, M
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I see:

```
julia> using TidierData

julia> df = DataFrame(a=1:4, b=["M", "F", "F", "M"])
4×2 DataFrame
 Row │ a      b
     │ Int64  String
─────┼───────────────
   1 │     1  M
   2 │     2  F
   3 │     3  F
   4 │     4  M

julia> @glimpse(df)
Rows: 4
Columns: 2
.a             Int64          1, 2, 3, 4
.b             String         M, F, F, M
```

(Note that this code snipped doesn't require `using DataFrames` as `TidierData` reexports some of the `DataFrames` API).

My best guess is that you are on an old version of `TidierData` which didn't have `@glimpse`, often the case when people install all their packages in the default environment.

Here's my environment status:

```
(jl_xs6Ua0) pkg> st
Status `Temp\jl_xs6Ua0\Project.toml`
  [fe2206b3] TidierData v0.12.2
```

Comment: This was it. I updated my version of `TidierData` and now it works. Thanks!

Comment: Glad it worked, consider making my answer or your own as the solution so that others know this question is resolved